# Review queue doesn't highlight respective vote arrow

Tags: bug, reviewing

Below are some screenshots (for those who have <10K when the answer gets deleted) of a UI bug I encountered while going through the review queue.

While viewing the answer on the question page, the arrow is highlighted for the respective vote I casted.

[image: Question with high-lighted vote]

While view the answer in the review queue, the arrow is *not* highlighted for the respective vote I casted.

[image: Question without high-lighted vote]

If I click the downvote (or upvote) arrows, I get the appropriate messages. So this is just a UI bug

Comment: [I actually posted about this on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381942/votes-do-not-appear-to-be-reflected-when-viewing-review-tasks-from-review-task-h) some time ago, which in turn was closed as a duplicate of another post that dates back to April 2022.

Comment: @TimmyJim Ah, I didn't realize that